# Does the Swiss law say that international health law supercedes national law?

Tags: public-health, switzerland

In [this video](https://rumble.com/vzmlta-7-2-.html), starting at about 28:40, Dr. [Astrid Stuckelberger](https://www.astridstuckelberger.com/) says

> Even the constitution of Switzerland there is a little line they have added without asking us, which says that **international law supercedes national law in the health matters.**

This seems strange in two aspects. First, as far as I know, it is not possible to add lines to the Swiss constitution without a referendum. Second, the contents of such law seems contrary to the Swiss principle of democracy.

Question: is there a line in the Swiss constitution, or elsewhere in Swiss law, that implies that international law supercedes national law in health matters?

Comment: Can you add a bit of background on who Astrid Stuckelberger is? The linked webpage gives her CV but does she have any political power or some official advisory role? Or is this just the personal opinion of some random public health researcher?

Comment: @quarague all I know about Astrid Stuckelberger is what I found in her web-page: she is Swiss; she is a faculty member in Geneva and Lausanne Universities;  and she worked with international health organizations. I would say that she is more than just "random public health researcher".

Comment: The video doesn't play for me. [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvfCGiNU0R4) claims she is a 'whistleblower'.

Comment: There is [another video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvfCGiNU0R4) where from about 10:00 Astrid claims *"When the Secretary General of WHO says something, all the member countries have to obey, under international law."*

Comment: For the [Swiss constitution itself](https://www.fedlex.admin.ch/eli/cc/1999/404/en), this seems a pretty clear No.  The only plausible reference to "health matters" is Article 118, which says that *the Confederation* shall take measures for the protection of health and legislate in certain related areas.  There is also Article 197, saying that Switzerland shall accede to the UN and accept the obligations of the [UN charter](https://www.un.org/en/about-us/un-charter/full-text), but the latter also doesn't appear to have anything relevant about health matters.

Comment: Do you want this as an answer?  Researching all the rest of Swiss law would be a much bigger task.

Comment: Astrid Stuckelberger seems to be really popular with the anti-vaxx crowd and people who think that Bill Gates is the root of all evil. Her Google scholar profile shows that the research she has published is mostly concerned with ageing (from both medical and social viewpoints). Her h index is 16, which I would consider rather unimpressive for somebody who claims to have been in medical research for 30 years. What I‘m trying to say: I‘m not sure this is a notable claim.

Comment: @NateEldredge In some countries, international treaties take precedence over ordinary law, in the sense that if a government does not abide by a treaty that it has signed, there is a legal recourse within the country's own judicial system (not necessarily as simple as directly allowing any judge to apply treaty provisions). If this is the case in Switzerland, and Switzerland has ratified a treaty related to health, then indeed some form of “international health law” would supersede national law in _some_ health matters, and this would not require a mention of health in the constitution.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil': Sure, and I would consider that to be part of "the rest of Swiss law".  But one wouldn't call it "a line in the constitution".

Comment: @DocM: On Skeptics.SE, notability is not the same as veracity. Notability means many people believe it (or as a proxy, many people have been exposed to it). Asking questions about widely-held claims from unreliable sources is our bread-and-butter.

Comment: @Oddthinking is there any evidence that anyone other than Astrid Stuckelberger believes this claim?

Comment: This might be better on law stack exchange as this seems like a basic legal question

Comment: @Oddthinking Do you now finally see the continued problems? 6 years regulars' comments counter policy with enough UVs 2tank? What's a comparative for repeatedly? This is fine? // To answer for you, on 'notability-attempts: the extract is from https://odysee.com/@GrandJury:f/Grand-Jury-Day-2-online_1:f with still +200k views on YT, +numerous other channels replaying this (&AS wasn't the only one with this story on similar channels;; actually this is a repeat performance of her in these circles…(grand-jury.net, or ex: https://www.oval.media/c7c409ea-a418-41cd-b0f8-ef908a13b5f5/)) delete as usual

Comment: @LangLаngС: I can't parse your question. At time of writing, this has 6 upvotes, no downvotes and no close votes. I am not seeing why this isn't fine.

Comment: @phoog: We accept as a proxy that many people have seen it. Only accepting questions about claims from highly reliable sources with good references would make this site redundant.

Comment: @Oddthinking what is it about this question that suggests that many people have seen the claim?  So far all I am aware of is that a Swiss academic (whom I've never heard of despite living in Geneva for the last 8 months) can be found making the claim in a video that is available on a site I've never heard of.  When I follow the link for the video, it is embedded in a page written in a language I do not read, and it seems to have been produced by an organization I've never heard of. The link for the academic is to her own website.  Where is the "evidence that [the] claim is notable"?

Comment: @Oddthinking I hasten to add that I'm not asserting that the claim isn't notable, isn't widely believed, or hasn't been seen by many people.  I am saying only that I haven't seen any evidence that would suggest otherwise.  If someone can point to that evidence, I'd consider writing an answer.  As it is, I tend to agree that the question belongs on [Law.SE], but I suspect that it would be rejected there because it's not clear what legal theory underlies Stuckelberger's conclusion about the supremacy of international law in health matters.

Comment: @Oddthinking It's about the unruly _comments_ showing _yet another_ incidence (you seem2keep denying) of long-term regulars violating site-rules: on comments & site-policy, showing: 'unskeptical' enough and in numbers enough, so that they can torpedo & deplatform any Q or A around here. (You want 'bad actors'? I show at least severe structural deficits. That's not fine.).// This Q is fine & notable enough: I provided hints & links to other outlets from which this snippet is taken, proving this claim was seen by _many, many_ more than the view count below the Hebrew subtitled snippet used here.

Comment: @LangLаngС Could you compose a meta post clearly explaining your point as it's really not clear in comment-shorthand. Also note, it's not about the post in question, thus derailing the conversation.

Comment: Seeing as there is a whole SE devoted to Law, should we not consider moving it there?